# /opt/nvidia-smi from nvidia-drivers pack outputs "failed to load nvidia kernel module"

Tags: linux, drivers, gentoo

Actually I have nouveau string in make.conf.

"Nvidia-smi has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Comment: 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a2)

Comment: *Please* try to include some basic information with your questions. As it stands almost all of the questions that you have made are not presented in such a way that it is easy to help.

Comment: Please add more information. What version of the nvidia-driver are you currently using? How did you install/activate it? What make.conf are you talking about? Have you DKMS installed as well?

Comment: wait i'm looking for these questions . /etc/portage/make.conf (for Gentoo it's main file)

Comment: Okey , i'm accustomed user of Q&A google (it's btw not serious at all) - so I'ts hard time for me to getting on with all this. More work less shortness of questions for audience... Trying to be more serious (eager to ..but habits(( I'll try. Maybe all my questions'd disappear or fulfilling myself or they would reemerge again with more vital argumentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect to use the proprietary `nvidia` driver's tools when you're running the open source `nouveau` driver.